# Terminal: Avoid repeating directory multiples times to reach files within

Tags: command-line, bash

I have two files `file1.txt` , `flie2.txt` in a directory `X`. I want to copy those files to my current working directory which is far away from the directory `X`.

so I end up with a command like:

```
cp ~/Desktop/dir/dir/dir/dir/file1.txt ~/Desktop/dir/dir/dir/dir/file2.txt .
```

Is there anyway to use the directory path once for both file, some kind of a shortcut ?
I am sure there is, Ubuntu never failed my laziness :D

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Use `[1-2]` to indicate the files, this uses `bash`'s range expansion feature :

```
cp ~/Desktop/dir/dir/dir/dir/file[1-2].txt .
```

Here the range `[1-2]` will expand so `file[1-2].txt` will expand to `file1.txt` and `file2.txt`.

Note that if you have multiple files like this with various number of numeric digits among their names :

```
file1.txt file12.txt file980.txt file0.txt file23.txt
```

In this case use the `extglob` feature of `bash` to enable extended pattern matching:

```
$ shopt -s extglob

$ cp ~/Desktop/dir/dir/dir/dir/file+([0-9]).txt .
```

The extglob pattern `+([0-9])` will match one or more digits between `file` and `.txt` in the file names.

Also note that it does not depend on any prefix or suffix, for example if you have files having names:

```
1 02 043 908
```

These can be matched (and copied) too by :

```
$ cp ~/Desktop/dir/dir/dir/dir/+([0-9]) .
```

Check `man bash` to get more idea on this.

Comment: Thank you, what is the name of this feature ? ( for future googling)

Comment: @Mhd.Tahawi Its called character range expansion..you might also be interested in character classes..

Comment: you sir, are awesome ! :)

Comment: what if the files didn't have any prefix in common, like `xx.x` and `yy.y` ? could it be used in the same way ?

Comment: @Mhd.Tahawi Check my edits

Answer (score 3):

I would use [brace expansion](http://mywiki.wooledge.org/BraceExpansion) for this kind of thing

```
cp -t ./ ~/Desktop/dir/dir/dir/dir/file{1..5}.txt

cp -t ./ ~/Desktop/dir/dir/dir/dir/{xx.x,yy.y}
```

Answer (score 1):

I'm using [History Expansion](https://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/bashref.html#History-Interaction) with [Word Designators](https://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/bashref.html#Word-Designators) a lot. `!$` will designate the last argument of the preceding command.

In most cases I take a look into that folder with `ls` first before coping.

```
$ ls ~/Desktop/dir/dir/dir/dir
file1.txt    file2.txt
$ cp !$/file1.txt !$/file2.txt .
cp ~/Desktop/dir/dir/dir/dir/file1.txt ~/Desktop/dir/dir/dir/dir/file2.txt .
```

As you can see bash automatically replaced `!$` with the last argument of the preceding command.

You can even use parts of that argument. `!$:h` (h for head) would designate the dirname of the last argument. `!$:t` (t for tail) would designate the basename of the last argument.

So, if you've read the file before with `less` you would do

```
$ less ~/Desktop/dir/dir/dir/dir/file1.txt
$ cp !$ !$:h/file2.txt .
cp ~/Desktop/dir/dir/dir/dir/file1.txt ~/Desktop/dir/dir/dir/dir/file2.txt .
```

Answer (score 1):

Question asked can be solved by using the following command too.

```
cp ~/Desktop/dir/dir/dir/dir/file*.txt .
```

it will copy any files with the naming style file(something in between).txt